# Django-models: Choices,select,widget How to change default options of widget

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have problem with models for example i have

```
fallBack = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=FALLBACK,  default = 99,blank = True,null = True)
FALLBACK = (
    (u'99','-'),
    (u'standard', u'Standard TPF deactivation/exlusion applies'),
    (u'fallback', u'Fallback script provided'),
    (u'na',u'N/A'),
    (u'other',u'Other'),
    )
```

if i will use in template

```
{% for obj in form.forms %}
    {{obj.fallBack}}
{% endfor %}
```

it will return sthing like this

```
<select name="form-0-fallBack" id="id_form-0-fallBack">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    <option value="99" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value="standard">Standard TPF deactivation/exlusion applies</option>
    <option value="fallback">Fallback script provided</option>
    <option value="na">N/A</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

But i wanna make something like this:

```
<select **onchange="javascript:make()"** name="form-0-fallBack" id="id_form-0-fallBack">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    <option value="99" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value="standard">Standard TPF deactivation/exlusion applies</option>
    <option value="fallback">Fallback script provided</option>
    <option value="na">N/A</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

How to do that ?? 
I can write in template this secound option instead of {{obj.fallBack}} but then  my formset.is_valid() dont work , and when i will do something like this:

```
1)I will choose from fallBack second option(Standard TPF deactivation/exlusion applies) 
2) submit,
3) I have some error in other place in template 
4) Then my obj.fallBack returning to default option (99 , -)
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the django documentation on [`Widgets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/)

```
widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'javascript:make()'})
```

This looks like a `ModelForm`, check out how to specify widgets for [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets)

Comment: All greate but im using models.Model :((